# Please help me debug my calculator program

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, loops, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator. Whenever I put in something like 25 * 4 / 10 , it divides 25 by 4. Here is the part of the code I think might be the problem:

```
    private void button16_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string[] calCulation = CALCULATION.Text.Split('-', '+', '/', 'X');
        int numOfItems = calCulation.Length;
        int count = 1;
        char[] Arius = new char[Hey.Length];
        foreach(char words in Hey)
        {
            int outlie = 0;
            Arius[outlie] = words;
            outlie++;
        }
        decimal final = 0M;
        decimal[] calCulate = new decimal[numOfItems];
        int countfreak = 0;
        foreach (string word in calCulation)
        {

            calCulate[countfreak] = Convert.ToDecimal(word);
            countfreak++;
        }
        int counting = 1;
        int countinghey = 0;
        decimal final2 = calCulate[0];

        while(count < numOfItems){


            switch(Arius[countinghey])
            {
                case 'X':
                    /*
                        final2 += final * calCulate[counting -1];
                        final2 = final2 * calCulate[counting];
                     */
                    final2 = final2 * calCulate[counting];
                    break;
                case '-':


                        final2 = final2 - calCulate[counting];
                    break;
                case '+':


                        final2 = final2 + calCulate[counting];
                    break;
                case '/':


                        final2 = final2 / calCulate[counting];
                    break;
            }
             counting++;
             countinghey++;
             count++;

        }
        CALCULATION.Text = Convert.ToString(final2);
    }
    public bool Parshing(string value, string typee)
    {

        int hixty = value.Length;
        string six = value.Substring(hixty - 1, value.Length - hixty + 1);
        int lam;
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(six, out lam);
        if (result == true||six == "")
        {
            CALCULATION.Text += typee;
            Hey += typee;
        }
        else
        {
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Add some break points and debug yourself. The best way to find the answer for this question.

Comment: button16, hey, final2, freak, num vs cal don't score any readability points.  These things matter.  A lot.  Because suddenly you can't debug the code anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat, you are not splitting correctly.

```
string[] calCulation = CALCULATION.Text.Split('-', '+', '/', 'X');
```

given that you typed:

```
 25 * 4 / 10
```

you should change your split from 'X' to '*'

```
string[] calCulation = CALCULATION.Text.Split('-', '+', '/', '*');
```

You will further need to change your case statement.  Or make sure your input is correct.

Comment: nooo actually i type in 25X4/10 oops i got messed up